# Can't aggregate with min and max in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So when I use the sum function when aggregating everything works well:

```
data_update = data_update.groupby([data_update['day_time'].dt.month, data_update['day_time'].dt.year]).agg('sum')
```

but when I use min I get this error:

```
data_update = data_update.groupby([data_update['day_time'].dt.month, data_update['day_time'].dt.year]).agg('min')
```

> ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 1, placement implies 20

Comment: Maybe `...).agg('min')`try `...)['day_time'].agg('min')`

Comment: If I use this won't I get the min date ?

Comment: can you provide sample data?

Comment: Data is private unfortunately, found the problem though

Answer (score 1):

Turns out upgrading pandas from 1.1.2 to 1.3.2 fixed the problem and gave me this warning instead which is no problem and makes total sense:

```
 FutureWarning: Dropping invalid columns in DataFrameGroupBy.min is deprecated. In a future version, a TypeError will be raised. Before calling .min, select only columns which should be valid for the function.
```